# Netboot error: Invalid kernel argument

Tags: arch-linux, syslinux, pxe, netboot

I'm trying to install Arch using the [Netboot Live System](https://releng.archlinux.org/pxeboot/) following these steps:

- [Install Syslinux on a SD card according to its wiki](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/HowTos#How_to_Create_a_Bootable_USB%3a_For_Linux).
- Copy the iPXE kernel image to the SD card.
- Create an syslinux.cfg file.

In the last step I used this content:

```
LABEL archnetboot
MENU LABEL Arch Linux Netboot Environment
KERNEL /ipxe.lkrn
```

But when the notebook starts it says:

```
SYSLINUX 6.02 EDD Copyright (C) 1994-2013 H. Peter Anvin et al
Loading /ipxe.lkrn... ok
Booting kernel failed: Invalid argument
boot:
```

So it seem like I need to pass some network kernel parameters or something like that, because I tried the image with Qemu and it works fine.

The notebook is connected to the net by its Ethernet port, and I enabled the Network Boot in the BIOS although as far I know it is irrelevant when you try to boot from iPXE.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have network boot in the bios chances are it is pxe, so just use that.

Comment: That seems more complicated as it implies to set up a server, or I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes, you need dhcp and tftp servers to do a netboot. which Is what ipxe does much like the pxe in your bios. the advantages ipxe offers is if you don't have a local pxe implementation, or it is broken, or doesn't do what you want you can use one that you can get the source code for. No It is not more complicated: instead of using bios to load syslinux from usb and use syslinux to load ipxe to load ipxelinux to load linux to install you just use your bios pxe to load pxelinux to load linux to install.